# What is the plural of pchelka?

Tags: перевод

How would I write pchelka (little bee, as a term of endearment) as a plural (as in my little bees)? 
Thank you x

Comment: Wiktionary is much better than stackexchange for factual questions like this
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0
Note that both singular and plural have the letter ё in them, not sure what is the proper transliteration for it.

Answer (score 4):

> пчёлки

for grammatical cases you can refer to this site: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Пчёлк**а** / пчёлк**и**.

Cannot add comments, so reply to @Pasha Syrnikov:

According to my foreign pass this should be written in latin characters like: Pch**e**lka / Pch**e**lki, however it has other (possibly better) variants: Pch**o**lka, Pch**yo**lka (RU ё -> LA o, yo, e).

Comment: Rules for transliteration in passports changed over time: [Transliteration table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian#Transliteration_table).